# Can multiple tests use the same data provider function

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have a spec file which needs to perform two different tests as seen in the 'it blocks'. These tests perform different types of form creation based on the FORM_TYPE passed to the createForm method written in its respective PageObject file.

The question here is can I pass the same data-provider function *plusprovider()* to both the it blocks

```
    var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');
    var createForms = [];


    describe('Sample test', function () {


        it('Login', function () {
            LoginPage.hitURL();
            LoginPage.login(userName, password);
            logger.info('Navigating to Home Page');
        });


        function plusProvider() {
            createForms.forEach(function (data) {



 createForms.push(createFormsBuilder.parseFormData(formData));
            });
            return createForms;
        }

        using(plusProvider, function (data) {
            it("Create form type of Users", function () {              
                CreateFormPage.createForm(data, USER)
            });
            logger.info('USER Form created successfully');
        });


        using(plusProvider, function (data) {
            it("Create form type of Users", function () {              
                CreateFormPage.createForm(data, FEEDBACK)
            });
            logger.info('FEEDBACK Form created successfully');
        });


        afterAll(function () {
            LogoutPage.logout();
            logger.info('Successfully logged out');
        });


    });
```

Comment: does it cause any errors?

Comment: It's a sample I created. Data provides npm page didn't provide much explanation